# Find the average velocity of gas atoms

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, ideal-gas

The following problem arose from trying to solve a textbook problem and I don't know if I made some miscalculation or I should assume something that I don't know. I'm given helium in a balloon and I know its pressure $p$ and its density $d$; I'm asked to find the average velocity $v$ of the atoms.

What I know is that in general the average kinetic energy $\langle E_{k}\rangle$ for a monoatomic gas is given by $\frac{3}{2}k_{b}T$ where $k_{b}$ is the boltzmann constant and $T$ the temperature. From this formula I got that my average velocity should satisfy $$v=\sqrt{\frac{3k_{b}T}{m}}.$$ Using the ideal gas law and the relation $R=N_{A}k_{b}$ I got
$$v=\sqrt{\frac{3k_{b}pV}{mnR}}.$$ Now I used the fact that $d=\frac{m}{V}$
to conclude that $$v=\sqrt{\frac{3p}{dnN_{a}}}.$$

It's probably a dumb question but if this is correct I should know how to find the number of moles in the balloon, something that I'm not quite sure how to do. Am I missing something trivial? Thanks in advance for any hint.

Comment: Did you double check the derivation (likely replaced something wrong when replacing for the density)? v should not be a function of the amount of gas, if your volume and mass double, v (or T) remains the same.

Comment: I did, but I might doing someting wrong "on purpose", I will expand my calculation editing the question.

Comment: This is silly nitpicking, but you are actually trying to find the average speed of the molecules in the balloon, the average velocity is given just by the velocity of the balloon itself and is independent of things like pressure and temperature.

Comment: Yes you are right, sorry for the confusion brought up my incorrect statement, I will edit.

Comment: m is the mass of a molecule, not the total mass of the gas. $d=nmN_A/V$

Comment: You are right, I guess after all it was a really silly mistake. Thank you.

Comment: you are welcomed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by @Wolphram jonny  my mistake was in using blindly the formula without questioning the nature of what I called $m$.

Comment: Hi smc makes sense. I didnt understand from this answer that you were saying “the question has been answered in the comments so I have the answer now, and the mistake I was making was in using blindly the formula without questioning the nature of what I called m.”  I didnt know *what* this answer meant. So i reviewed your question and the comments. Maybe consider deleting the question or editing this answer. Oh, one option is to cut and paste what i just wrote.